# Manna From Heaven One who took more had nothing extra and one who took less wasn't laking

Tags: torah-study, commentaries, faith-bitachon-emunah, exodus, manna

"One who took more had nothing extra and one who took less wasn't laking" (Shemot 16:18)

What does it mean? One who took more was satisfied with more meaning he ate everything and was Satisfied and one who took less was also satisfied with less if yes didn't we all came back with an equal "Omer le Gulgolet (Shemot 16:16)" an Omer measure for every person no matter what?

Or Does it mean if a man went to collect alot more then an Omer measure Hashem made it that he didn't have extra meaning that he gave him no more than just an Omer so it wouldn't be unfair to everyone else who is supposed to just get one Omer and the one who took less Hashem also made sure he came back with an Omer maybe because the man who went to gather was tired and hungry that day and because Hashem "gives food to the hungry" (Psalms 147:7) therefore he made sure that even the one who took less wasn't lacking an omer?

And if yes that we only had one Omer how could this sustain everyone equally and perfectly fine what if someone was more hungry that day?

Comment: Seems like the simple meaning is that there was just the right amount: no one collected extra and no one fell short.